# Quotient of a free group by a subgroup of the commutator

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, free-groups

> Let $F$ be the free group on finitely many generators $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$. Let $[F,F]\subseteq F$ be its commutator, so we know $F/[F,F]\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$, and let $N\subseteq F$ be a normal subgroup with the property $N\subseteq [F,F]$. Is it true that $F/N$ is torsion-free?

It was just a conjecture. I have a family of finite aspherical cell complexes whose fundamental groups are of this form, and I thought that the torsion-freeness of them has an easier, purely algebraic reason.

Comment: No it's not always true, why should it be?

Comment: It was just a conjecture. I have a family of finite aspherical cell complexes whose fundamental groups are of this form, and I thought that the torsion-freeness of them has an easier, purely algebraic reason.

Comment: Do you have a counterexample, @DerekHolt?

Comment: @FKranhold: Just take the normal closure of $[x_1,x_2]^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the multiplicative group of matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & a & c\\
0 & 1 & b\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right),$$
where $a$ and $b$ are integers, and $c$ is an integer modulo $n\gt 1$.

This group is nilpotent of class $2$; it is generated by the element with $a=1$, $b=c=0$ and the element with $b=1$, $a=c=0$. The commutator of these two elements is the element with $a=b=0$, $c=1$, which is a torsion element. If you mod out by the subgroup generated by $c$, we get $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

If we look at this group as a quotient of the free group in two elements $F$ under the obvious map, the kernel $N$ is contained in the commutator subgroup $[F,F]$. But the group is torsion (the commutator subgroup is nontrivial and finite). Thus, $F/N$ is not torsionfree.

More generally, in your free group, if you let $N$ be the normal closure of $[x_i,x_j]^k$, $i\neq j$, $k\gt 1$, then the quotient will have torsion. That the normal closure is contained in $[F,F]$ is, I hope, clear.

Comment: In your final paragraph, it's less clear that $F/N$ contains torsion. (It *is* true, but it's a non-trivial theorem of Karrass, Magnus and Solitar.)

Comment: @user1729: One can construct a two generator group in which $[x_i,x_j]$ is nontrivial, but $[x_i,x_j]^k$ is trivial. This guarantees that $F/N$ has torsion. You don’t need to bring in the powerful theorem you mention.

Comment: It just clicked that the $x_i$ are part of a free basis, so then we can use HNN-extensions to see that $F/N$ has torsion. But this is still quite heavy machinery, right? So I'm intrigued your point about constructing an image with this property: which groups were you thinking of?

Comment: @user1729: Nilpotent groups suffice. In fact, nilpotent groups of class two.

Comment: Oh, wait, I understand now! In fact, we can just look at finite groups, and if you don't care about the precise order of the commutator, but just that it has finite order, than you just note that there are two-generated non-abelian finite groups. If you do care about the order then for example dihedral groups work (as by my calculations (possibly incorrect!) the commutator of the flip generator $a$ and the rotate generator $b$ is just $b^2$, so it's order is easily found). Thanks, I feel I've learned something today!

Comment: @user1729: You don’t want to look at finite groups, because then the $N$ you are moding out by is not contained in $[F,F]$, and you don’t know if the finite order is a consequence of the finite order of the generators outside of $[F,F]$. But you can easily build nilpotent groups in which the torsion is completely contained in the commutator, such as the 2-generator one I built explicitly above.

Comment: What I mean is that if we take $N$ to be the normal closure of $[a, b]^3$, say, in $F(a, b)$ then $F/N$ surjects onto $S_3$. As $[a, b]$ has order at most three in $F/N$, and has order precisely three in $S_3$, we conclude that it has order three in $F/N$. That is, the images don't need to have relators in the derived subgroup, they just need to witness the properties we are after.